# Data enrichment for multiple pubsub topics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I have 2 topics:

**player_info_topic**
example message:

```
{"id": 1, "name": "Sandy"}
```

**seating_arrangement_topic**
example message:

```
{"id": 1, "seat": 2}
```

Is there a way to match these messages in gcp, cloud dataflow maybe then publish to another pubsub topic?

Answer (score 2):

In streaming, joins can only be done if you apply a window to the `PCollection`s to be joined. The window has to be either a `FixedWindow` or a `SlidingWindow`.

You could read from the two topics, and then add a key to each element with the id in the two resulting `PCollection`s. Then add the window, and apply the   `CoGroupByKey`. Then generate the output in the format that you want to write to Pubsub, and send it to Pubsub.

Have a look at the examples [for Python](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/cogroupbykey/), [for Java](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/java/aggregation/cogroupbykey/) and the [section about CoGroupByKey in the Beam Programming Guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#cogroupbykey)